# Create cells in UITableView in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

My question is, how do I create a dynamic prototype cell in a UITableView. I looked trough the internets a bit and only found tutorials and code for UITableViewControllers but not for UITableViews,which i would like to use in my application. So it would be nice if anyone could help out with some code.

THX appreciate it.

Comment: It's pretty much the same, you just set the delegate and datasource of your UITableView to the ViewController that contains it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code to create `UITableView`:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    let tableData = ["1","2","3","4"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

        tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

        return tableData.count
    }



    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

        var cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.tableData[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Happy to help you..:)